# Any function in testcafe that could test sorted columns in a table?

Tags: sorting, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there any function implemented to check if the column is displayed in descending order or not?
There's scenario where clicking on a sort, i.e. sort the name/EmailId from Z to A, then the listing should be sorted alphabetically from Z to A.

Is there any strategy that I can apply using testcafe?

Comment: Your task does not seem to be TestCafe related. Check out all available Test API at http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/.
 
The algorithm you will use to check this completely depends on the table you are using and its sorting method implementation. For instance, if there's a sort indicator on your table, you may check its state. If there are no indicators, you may collect your column data, sort it, and compare it with the original data source. If the results are equal, the data is sorted in the manner you expected to check.

Comment: If you have an access to values, you can just ensure that each next value is always less than previous one

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with a big ol' "technically".

As [@alex-skorkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312771/alex-skorkin) noted, this isn't specific to TestCafe.
This answer builds on [@roman-eremin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312771/roman-eremin)'s comment

**If you're testing strings...**

`await t.expect(cell <= compareCell).ok();` to test ascending
`await t.expect(cell >= compareCell).ok();` to test descending

**If you're testing numbers...**

`await t.expect(cell).lte(compareCell);` to test ascending
`await t.expect(cell).gte(compareCell);` to test descending

**Full pseudo test case (for strings)**

```
test('Should be Sorted ASC', async t => {
    const cellSelector = Selector('td[name="sortable-cell"]');
    const cellCount = await cellSelector.count;

    for (let i = 0; i < cellCount - 1; i++) {
        let cellText = await cellSelector.nth(i).innerText;
        let compareCellText = await cellSelector.nth(i + 1).innerText;

        await t.expect(cellText <= compareCellText).ok();
    }
})
```